# Is it better to use methods over closures?

Tags: go, methods, closures

I have a simple type of data that only consists of an uint32, but many operations can be performed on this data. All files that use this data reside in the same package and therefore can access the unexported uint32 inside the struct which is not preferable. I recently learned about the power of closures and was wondering if it is better to use a struct that contains functions that perform the tasks or to have the uint32 stored in the struct and then just use methods with a receiver of the struct.

This is a basic representation of an OpenGL shader. Both the method and closure options, look the same to the caller but perform differently under the hood.

Closure:

```
type Shader struct {
    getID  func() uint32
    delete func()
}

func CreateShader(shader string) Shader {
    var id uint32
    //Do work...
    return Shader{
        getID: func() uint32 {
            return id
        },
        delete: func() {
            gl.DeleteShader(id)
        },
    }
}
```

Methods:

```
type Shader struct {
    id uint32
}

func CreateShader(shader string) Shader{
    var id uint32
    //Do work...
    return Shader{id: id}
}

func (s Shader) getID() uint32 {
    return s.id
}

func (s Shader) delete() {
    gl.DeleteShader(s.id)
}
```

Both options appear like this in use:

```
func main() {
    shader := CreateShader("shader.code")
    id := shader.getID()
    fmt.Println(id)
    shader.delete()
}
```

The miss use I thought to avoid was that the caller could affect the id type without Shader knowing. Something similar to:

```
shader.id = 4102 // or some other change
```

With the use of closures this behavior is impossible and requires the caller to go use the proper calls.

As mentioned in the comments, it is possible to use a shader package and unexport the shader type. I didn't use this because I thought it was improper to make an entire package just to hold one file. But perhaps it is proper if it solidifies correct use of the type.

Is there any reason that the closure version is "wrong" compared to the methods? Are there any golang standards that would classify either choice better suited for my use case? I expect the caller to not touch the id of the shader and think that the use of closures makes it clearer the proper use of the shader type.

Comment: What is the misuse you are trying to protect against with closures?  The second approach is more idiomatic and therefore should be more obvious how to use correctly.

Comment: Why don't you have a shader package to encapsulate the Shader type and its methods?

Comment: and if the shader package is only of use to your parent package - and not to any external code - use go [internal packages](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages)

Comment: This is more about if the code is idiomatic and less about its use case. Although, that is important info. Personally, I thought it was an interesting use of closures. This was more of an example and less about an actual use case which like Ceris Limon said it would be obvious the correct use if methods were used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closures and methods solve entirely different problems, so it's rare that you should ever ask which one to use in a particular situation.

Having said that, closures *can be* a way to provide data protection, and are often (ab)used for this in languages which don't otherwise offer private variables (i.e. JavaScript).

There's no reason to ever use them *for this purpose* in Go.

Comment: I know that pointers cause a cache failure because they must be looked up. If having the receiver be a pointer has noticeable overhead would that affect the decision to use closures? Or is that a decision that can only be determined after profiling? Also, exactly what problems do each solve?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does "pointers cause a cache failure because they must be looked up" mean? In any case, if your concern is performance, the answer is always that it can only be determined after profiling.